# Web/Push Notifications and Accessibility

Tags: accessibility, web-notifications

I would like to know if there is any information or support available regarding Accessibility features with respect to Web Notifications on Chrome and Firefox browsers.
We are trying to implement Web Notifications using the Notifications API https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/ and are unable to use keyboard to get focus to the web notification in the bottom right. We can though access the Accept/Block popup that requests the permission to allow notifications when we use keyboard tab or spacebar. We believe it is a very important ability to support people with disabilities.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Great question, I've upvoted it. Do you have a demo we can look at?

Comment: Here is the sample code that can be executed in console while any webpage is open. example. access google.com and in the chrome or firefox inspector execute this code.
`if ("Notification" in window) {
  Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { 
    console.log('Permission is ' + permission); 
    if (permission === 'granted') { 
      new Notification('Title of the web push notification', {"icon": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwoSg.png", "body": "This is where the body of the web notification shows up."}); 
    } 
  });
}`

Comment: You will observe that when you use tab on the request notification popup, you are able to select accept or block buttons, but after you accept and the notification appears, we can't use tab/keyboard to access it.

Comment: This is an interesting question, however you need to contact the people who are making the standard on GitHub or contact the browser manufacturers through their bug trackers (e.g. Chromium). I don't think it's something that the website developers can improve directly.